# Backwards substitute in matlab after finding a solution.

Tags: matlab

So I have this code here (For a electrical problem)

```
R_1= input('Enter the value of R_1 ');
R_2= input('Enter the value of R_2 ');
R_3= input('Enter the value of R_3 ');
V_1= input('Enter the value of V_1 ');
V_2= input('Enter the value of V_2 ');
V_3= input('Enter the value of V_3 ');
syms V_a
i_1=(V_a-V_1)/R_1;
i_2=(V_a-V_2)/R_2;
i_3=(V_a-V_3)/R_3;
eqn1 = i_1+i_2+i_3==0;
solV_a = solve(eqn1,V_a);
```

This is all fine as my last line solves for V_a however after matlab solves for V_a, I want matlab to back substitute this V_a value back into i_1,i_2,i_3 and then display the *new* i_1,i_2,i_3 numerical value. I learnt there is a sub function in matlab but not sure how to implement it into my code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `subs` function to update the symbolic variable `V_a` with the value found for `solV_a` like so:

```
subs(i_1, V_a, solV_a)
```

This will return `i_1` evaluated at the value found for `V_a` by the equation solver.